# Связь моделей баз данных Flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

возникла такая проблема при попытке создания таблиц, не пойму как правильно сделать. Создаю 3 модели, пытаюсь сделать между ними связь () Подскажите, пожалуйста.

1)

```
class User(SqlAlchemyBase, UserMixin, SerializerMixin):
   __tablename__ = 'users'

   id = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
   surname = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String)
   name = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String)
   age = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Integer)
   position = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String)
   speciality = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String)
   address = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String)
   email = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String, unique=True)
   hashed_password = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String)
   modified_date = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.DateTime)
   jobs = orm.relationship('Job')
   departments = orm.relationship('Department')
```

2. 

```
class Job(SqlAlchemyBase, SerializerMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'jobs'

    id = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    team_leader = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Integer,
                                    sqlalchemy.ForeignKey('users.id'))
    job = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String)
    work_size = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Integer)
    collaborators = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String)
    start_date = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.DateTime,
                                   default=datetime.datetime.now(), nullable=True)
    end_date = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.DateTime, nullable=True)
    is_finished = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.BOOLEAN)
    category_id = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Integer,
                                    sqlalchemy.ForeignKey('categories.id'), nullable=True)
    category = orm.relationship('Category', back_populates='job')
    user = orm.relation('User')
```

3

```
class Category(SqlAlchemyBase, SerializerMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'categories'

    id = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    title = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String)
    job = orm.relationship('Job', back_populates='category')
```

Сделать пытаюсь связь (2 с 1 и 2 с 3)

Ошибка

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: When initializing mapper mapped class Job->jobs, expression 'Category' failed to locate a name ('Category'). If this is a class name, consider adding this relationship() to the <class 'data.job.Job'> class after both dependent classes have been defined.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, relation
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):
   __tablename__ = 'users'

   id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
   jobs = relationship('Job')
   departments = relationship('Department')


class Job(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'jobs'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    category = relationship('Category', back_populates='job')
    user = relation('User')


class Category(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'categories'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    title = Column(String)
    job = relationship('Job', back_populates='category')
```

Я немного упростил ваш пример, но связи оставил, работает...

Comment: к сожалению, нет, такая же ошибка

Comment: ключевой момент заключается, наверное, в том, что у меня из **Job** идут 2 связи с 2 разными таблицами, если в этом проблема, то как это реализовать?

Comment: Скопируйте мой пример и попробуйте запустить. У меня ошибки не было, я проверял.

Comment: вопрос ещё актуален? @kldd0

Comment: да, пожалуй, еще да

Comment: Честно говоря - по вашему описанию - мой ответ довольно сильно подходит и имеет связь с необходимыми моделями.

Вы можете описать более точно вопрос, возможно тогда вы получите более точный ответ.

Перепишите вопрос, код - оставьте только необходимые вещи.